# How to refresh the excel file in network?

Tags: excel

In my work, I have the access to the excel file with the list of customers, that is stored on the network drive. The list of the customers is updated every few minutes by another employee. In order to see new added customers on the list, I have to close the file and reopen it. It's quite annoying as the file weight a couple of MB and it lasts ~20 seconds to reopen it. Is there any way to refresh the already opened file (without reopening it), so the new-added customers just appear on the list in the next rows? I don't mean using VBA as I just have a read-only access to the file.

Comment: Rather than opening the file, in a separate workbook create a query that gets the list you want.  Then refresh that query, either manually or on a schedule

Comment: Unfortunately, in order to get data from another file with a query, the queried file must be opened. So to query the new-added rows, the queried file must be re-opened first, so it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: The ":so the new-added customers just appear on the list." part NEED's vba. afaik normal excel code cannot do that. || Alternative (to try) : Data > (Get external data) From other sources (or you may use the others if it applicable)